# what's wrong with string contains match

Tags: vb.net

Sorry, I don't want to post this question here. Other questions like mine have been posted before, but I haven't found an answer yet.

I am trying to do a simple string match using string.contains

```
 If Not dataRow("Name").ToString().Contains(UserName) Then
  --do something--
End If
```

but that's not working in my condition

```
dataRow("Name").ToString()= "Steve Cook"
UserName="Cook Steve"
```

I want to find the `%like` match (like SQL) but `.contains` not what I was expecting it to do?

Comment: you could simply find the reason by debugging it and stepping through the code

Comment: So you are expecting "Steve Cook".Contains("Cook Steve") to return true?

Comment: Ofcourse i know why its not. ("Steve Cook").contains ("Cook Steve") but that's not my question. My question is contains work like "%like%" in sql ?

Comment: I had the impression ".Contains" work like matching the sting the one in SQL (%Like%).

Comment: @Usher do you think doing `WHERE 'Steve Cook' LIKE '%Cook Steve%'` would work in sql? no. same reason applies here.

Comment: @Aominè, how stupid am I.That's correct it won't in sql either

Comment: @Usher `WHERE columnName LIKE '%somevalue%'` is the equivalent of `variableName.Contains(somevalue)` , `WHERE columnName LIKE 'somevalue%'` is the equivalent of `variableName.StartsWith(somevalue)` ,  `WHERE columnName LIKE '%somevalue'` is the equivalent of `variableName.EndsWith(somevalue)` and if you want to do more complex pattern matching then use the `Regex.IsMatch` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the problem by using [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions). Regex is comparable to using wildcards but allows you to express much more complex search patterns. Google for Regex tutorials. You will find lots of them.

```
Dim s As String = dataRow("Name").ToString()
If Not Regex.IsMatch(s, "\bSteve\s+Cook\b|\bCook\s+Steve\b") Then
    ' do something
End If
```

Requires

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

The meaning of this Regex expression is: find the whole words (i.e. not only parts of words imbedded in a longer word) "Steve Cook" OR "Cook Steve" that are separated by at least one space character.

Answer (score 2):

It has to be an exact part of the string, in your case the field does not contain “Cook Steve” like you’re asking, it contains (“Steve” and “Cook”) or (“Steve Cook”)

You need to split on the spaces and check each word. But you could find some cases where you’ll get false positives.

Answer (score 2):

A simple Comparer Class.
If the strings differ in length or not all parts are equal, returns `false`

```
Dim names As Names = New Names
names.CompareName = "Steve Cook"
names.ToName = "Cook steve"

If names.Compare(True) = True Then
 Console.Write("Same guy")
End If

Public Class Names
  Public Property CompareName() As String
  Public Property ToName() As String

  Public Function Compare(ByVal IgnoreCase As Boolean) As Boolean
     If CompareName.Length <> ToName.Length Then Return False

     Dim TypeOfComparison As StringComparison = 
         If(IgnoreCase, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, 
                        StringComparison.InvariantCulture)
     Dim _All As Boolean = True
     Dim _parts As String() = ToName.Split(" "c)
     For Each _part As String In _parts
        If CompareName.IndexOf(_part, 0, TypeOfComparison) < 0 Then
           _All = False
           Exit For
        End If
     Next
     Return _All
  End Function
End Class
```

Or with a Join-Split-Reverse:

```
Dim Name1 As String = "Steve Cook"
Dim Name2 As String = "Cook Steve"

If StringCompare(Name1, Name2) Then
    Console.Write("Same guy")
End If

Public Function StringCompare(ByVal CompName As String, ByVal ToName As String) As Boolean
   If CompName.Equals(ToName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
       Return True
   End If
   If CompName.Equals(String.Join(" ", ToName.Split(" "c).AsEnumerable.Reverse()),
                      StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
      Return True
   End If
   Return False
End Function
```